# How to access 64 bit JNI lib using 32 bit Java 8 Embedded JRE

Tags: java, linux

I created my custom JRE using Java 8 Embedded (I think it only support 32 bit JVM)

System : Linux X86_64

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/java-embedded-java-se-download-359230.html

when i access a 64 BIT system JNI library from my code .I get the following exception

"  Native library (linux-x86/xyz.so) not found in resource path "

but I've  the corresponding 64 bit xyz.so in the java library path.I didn't get the 32 bit version of xyz.so lib .Is there any way i can access the 64 JNI lib from 32 bit JVM.
Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. You need a 32-bit library or a 64-bit JVM.